# Exception message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sql

```
2018-11-20T09:31:12+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0-hunderefleksvest-str-m' for key 'UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_URL_KEY_STORE_ID_VALUE', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_url_key` (`entity_type_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES (\?, \?, \?, \?, \?)
Trace: #0 /var/www/parkogfritid.dk/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
1 /var/www/parkogfritid.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
2 /var/www/parkogfritid.dk/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
3 /var/www/parkogfritid.dk/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
4 /var/www/parkogfritid.dk/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
5 /var/www/parkogfritid.dk/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(576): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
6 /var/www/parkogfritid.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Url.php(563): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('catalog_product...', Array)
7 /var/www/parkogfritid.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(374): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Url->saveProductAttribute(Object(Varien_Object), 'url_key')
8 /var/www/parkogfritid.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(562): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->_refreshProductRewrite(Object(Varien_Object), Object(Varien_Object))
9 /var/www/parkogfritid.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(255): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshProductRewrites('1')
10 /var/www/parkogfritid.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(248): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshRewrites('1')
11 /var/www/parkogfritid.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Indexer/Url.php(257): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshRewrites()
12 /var/www/parkogfritid.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Catalog_Model_Indexer_Url->reindexAll()
13 /var/www/parkogfritid.dk/public_html/app/code/local/Mirasvit/Fpc/Model/Index/Process.php(108): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
14 /var/www/parkogfritid.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mirasvit_Fpc_Model_Index_Process->reindexAll()
15 /var/www/parkogfritid.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(182): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
16 /var/www/parkogfritid.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->massReindexAction()
17 /var/www/parkogfritid.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('massReindex')
18 /var/www/parkogfritid.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
19 /var/www/parkogfritid.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
20 /var/www/parkogfritid.dk/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
21 /var/www/parkogfritid.dk/public_html/index.php(95): Mage::run('', 'store')
22 {main}
```

Anyone could help me out here to solve this matter?

Comment: It looks like your have two products that share the same url key 0-hunderefleksvest-str-m

Answer (score 0):

You may have a custom url rewrite in your database that causes a problem with reindex process.

Look for custom rewrites and remove the problematic one in admin panel.

Comment: Could it help to truncate the core_url_rewrite?

Comment: It's not recommended if you have custom rewrites. 
Debug the $rewriteData in the catch block of saveRewrite() function in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Url.php. It should have the store_id and id_path of your problematic rewrite.